# MYSQL WHERE condition depends upon SELECT column

Tags: mysql, select, where-clause, conditional-statements

Is it possible to reference back to the column you're selecting in the WHERE condition?

I'm not even sure how to ask this question without excessive verbage, so I'll just try to point you to the "rated_user = @2User" part and note that @2User is what I'm selecting.

```
SELECT id, user, minimum 
INTO @1ID, @1User, @minimum 
FROM table1 
WHERE a_or_b = 'a' AND item = itemName 
ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1;

SELECT id, user 
INTO @2ID, @2User 
FROM table1 
WHERE a_or_b = 'b' AND item = itemName 
    AND (SELECT IFNULL(AVG(rating),0) AS Rating 
            FROM table2 
            WHERE rated_user = @2User AND completed = 'y'
        ) >= @minimum_seller_rating 
ORDER BY number ASC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use the original column name and  say `where rated_user = user` ?

Comment: I had no idea that's possible.  Trying now...

Comment: works.  thanks.  don't want to answer for credit?

Comment: @Thilo just dropping you a note to post your answer as an answer, so that Op can accept it.

Comment: if you select something in the outer query you can reference it in the sub query as you have used in the where clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just use the original column name from the parent table in the sub query as well.

```
WHERE rated_user = user
```

If there is a name collision, you may need to prefix it with the table name or alias.

```
WHERE rated_user = table1.user
```